# Что такое build minutes

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

Когда выбираешь тарифный план bitbucket, стоит, что бесплатно до 50 build minutes. Что это значит? Важно ли это для хранения Laravel проекта? Если есть два users, которые обмениваются изменениями.

Comment: Минуты сборки в месяц фактически ограничивают сколько раз вы можете выполнять сборку с помощью Pipelines, т.е. количество сборок в месяц = минуты сборки / время сборки.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, а зачем нужна сборка для PHP проекта? Как я понимаю, на сервере лежит просто папка с файлами, где главный index. То есть для небольшого Laravel проекта (совсем небольшого) это важный параметр?

Comment: Это просто возможность аккаунта. Через Pipelines можно настроить автоматическое тестирование, автоматический деплой сайта. Если вы не используете автотесты, вручную деплоите, то вам не важно сколько там минут сборки.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!